# Child replaced by another child

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in AS3.

I've got childs, named emptyspace, added to my stage in my Engine.as like that :

```
    emptyspace= new EmptySpace(stage, usableItems[0]);
    addChild(emptyspace);
    emptyspace2= new EmptySpace2(stage, usableItems[0]);
    addChildAt(emptyspace2, 0);
```

Each emptyspace got is own class (EmptySpace.as and EmptySpace2.as).

When I click on an emptyspace, a useBox appears (UseBox.as)

**Is it possible to save "in memory" wich emptyspace was clicked but use it later ?**

Because, then, the player choose in the useBox if he wants to build or not.

If he clicks on "build", a window opens with different buildings (Building.as).

Now, I was wondering if it's possible that, when he clicks on "Library" for exemple, the Library appears on the emptyspace wich was clicked before ("the saved click") ?

For the moment, I've got this code :

When he clicks on "Library" in the Building window it' calling this function :

```
private function poulaillerConstruction(e:MouseEvent):void{
            Engine.library.buildIt(e);
            Engine.building.visible = false;
}
```

In the Library.as :

```
public function buildIt(e:MouseEvent):void{
    stageRef.addChild(this);
    this.visible = true;    
    }
```

**So, for the moment, it appears anywhere on the screen (always at the same place of course) and not where the emptyspace was.**

(And if I click on the second empty space, the Library appears at the same place that the first...Don't want that either).

Any idea ?

Thank you very much,

---

**EDIT**

So, I've put in my **Engine.as**

```
emptyspace.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onEmptySpaceClicked);

private function onEmptySpaceClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("click on it neww");
   var myVar = e.currentTarget;
                    if (e.currentTarget.name == emptyspace){
                        //Don't know what to put
                    }
if (e.currentTarget.name == emptyspace2){

                    }           
}
```

So now, how can I do to put in my buildIt function in Tower.as "Listen the e.currentTarget.name ?

Something like this ? :

```
public function buildIt(e:MouseEvent):void{
if (e.currentTarget.name == emptyspace){
//Build here
}
if (e.currentTarget.name == emptyspace2){
//Build here
}   
    }
```

And what is the code to tell "Build here ON the emptyspace clicked" ?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

You can store the 'currentTarget' (the object which called the listener) that you clicked on. So providing you've created an eventlistener on an emptyspace:

```
emptyspace.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onEmptySpaceClicked);
```

For the button handler for each emptyspace you can capture that object in a class variable 'myVar:EmptySpace' like this:

```
function onEmptySpaceClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
   myVar = e.currentTarget;
   // do something more
}
```

**EDIT :**

I'm not sure if this is what you need clarification on or not...

You mentioned you wanted to save which emptyspace was selected for later, so in the onEmptySpaceClicked handler I'm not sure what your reason for putting an if statement is. If you want to let other objects know an empty space has been selected you could use dispatchEvent within the if statement when an emptySpace is clicked but I'm not sure that's best way to go.

If you have a buildingManager you could have the if statement call a method and pass the reference to which EmptySpace was clicked. It depends on your design..

```
           if (e.currentTarget.name == emptyspace){
                    buildManager.buildCurrentBuilding(myVar);
                }
```

Although with the above you wouldn't need an if statement, you would just let the handler send the myVar to buildingManager. It's only if you wanted something different to happen on each EmptySpace that you would need the if statement.

To add a displayObject at a later time into an emptyspace you would use

```
myVar.addChild(displayBuildingToAdd);
```

Engine.as might serve up the reference with a getter:

```
public function get currentEmptySpace():EmptySpace {

    return myVar;

}
```

you would need to pass myVar to whichever 'building' or buildingManager is wanting to add the building to an emptyspace.

Comment: Thank you, but there something that I can't figure out. I've edited my post.